# Composite Design Pattern with unequal weightage

Tags: design, design-patterns, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, composition

You have a video game in which upon killing final boss you get coins that get distributed based on whether you are:

1. Person(individual)
2. Group(consists of individuals or groups)

If reward for killing monster is 100. And the Fighters that killed monster together are:

```
  var joe = new Person("Joe");//Person
  var jake = new Person("jake");//Person
  var emily = new Person("emily");//Person

  var oldBob = new Person("oldBob");//Person that belongs to a group
var newBob = new Person("newBob");//Person that belongs to a group
      var familyGroup = new Group("familyGroup", new List<IFighter>() { newBob, oldBob });
```

The output will be:

**OUTPUT:**

```
You have killed the Giant IE6 Monster and gained 100 gold!
MegaParty has 100 gold coins.
familyGroup has 25 gold coins.
--newBob has 13 gold coins.
--oldBob has 12 gold coins.
--Joe has 25 gold coins.
--jake has 25 gold coins.
--emily has 25 gold coins.
```

with the below code:

**Interface:**

```
public interface IFighter
{
    string Name { get; }
    int Gold { get; set; }      
    void Stats();
}
**CLIENT:**

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int goldForKill = 100;
        Console.WriteLine("You have killed the Giant IE6 Monster and gained {0} gold!", goldForKill);
        var joe = new Person("Joe");
        var jake = new Person("jake");
        var emily = new Person("emily");
        var oldBob = new Person("oldBob");
        var newBob = new Person("newBob");
        var familyGroup = new Group("familyGroup", new List<IFighter>() { newBob, oldBob });
        var parties = new Group("MegaParty", new List<IFighter> { familyGroup, joe, jake, emily });
        parties.Gold += goldForKill;
        parties.Stats();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

**Person:**

```
public class Person : IFighter
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public int Gold { get; set; }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;            
    }

    public void Stats()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("--{0} has {1} gold coins.", Name, Gold);
    }
}
```

**Group:**

```
public class Group : IFighter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<IFighter> Members { get; set; }
    public int Gold
    {
         get
         {
             int totalGold=0;
            foreach (var member in Members)
            {
                totalGold += member.Gold;
            }
            return totalGold;
        }
        set
         {
            var eachSplit = value /this.Members.Count;;
            var leftOver = value % this.Members.Count;;
            foreach (var member in Members)
            {
                member.Gold = eachSplit +leftOver;
                leftOver = 0;
            }
         }
        }

        public Group(string name, List<IFighter> members)
        {
            Name = name;
            Members = members;
        }    

        public void Stats()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} has {1} gold coins.", this.Name, Gold);
            foreach (var member in Members)
            {
                member.Stats();
            }
        }
    }
```

**But, what if we were to give 10% extra weightage to those Person who belong to a group or a certain group? 
I could create class such as:**

`Female:IFighter, SeniorCitizen:IFighter` to whom I want to give extra weightage.

**How do you go about it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not put any "setter" for `Gold` into `IFighter`, and only implement a setter for this property in the `Person` class, not in the `Group` class.

The amount of `Gold` for a group is the total sum of all the gold of all group members, that makes sense. But when gold is assigned to a group, how it is distributed specificially to each person is *specific game logic* (even if it is distributed equally, which requires a decision of whom to give the `leftOver` amount). Such specific game logic should IMHO not be a responsibility of the `Composite` itself.

One could, however, provide specific methods inside the `Group` class, like

- `DistributeGoldEvenlyAmongMembers(int gold)`, or
- `DistributeGoldWeightedAmongMembers(int gold, /* maybe extra parameters here*/)`

The benefit here is that is becomes ultimately clear that adding gold to a group is quite different operation than just adding the gold to a single person.

This could also be implemented somewhere outside, for example in a controller class which runs the aftermath of a fight. And yes, this will may require some type checkings if an object is a person or a group, but that is quite natural if the game logic requires it.

Alternatively, to make more generic operations possible, one could add a method

```
 IEnumerable<Person> GetAllPersons()
```

to the `IFighter` interface, which should deliver a flattened enumeration of all persons in the `IFighter` unit (the person itself, or the members of the group as well as each member of a subgroup). Such a method can be used to create, for example, some scoring logic which implements this "10% extra weightage" rule in a generic fashion which does not need to make a distinction between individuals and groups.

Answer (score 1):

To get a different allocation than everybody the same portion, you can extend the `IFighter` interface with a `Share` property, which indicates (in a double) what portion of the gold should be given to that party member. A value of 1 should be the default and if everybody has a share of 1, then they all get an equal portion (give or take the left overs after rounding). If somebody has a share of 1.1, they would get approximately 10% extra.

The share of a group would typically *not* be the sum of the shares of its members, but the default 1. How the group sub-divides its portion of the gold is up to the group itself.

For example:

```
public interface IFighter
{
    string Name { get; }
    double Share { get; }
    int Gold { get; set; }      
    void Stats();
}

public class Person : IFighter
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public double Share { get; }
    public int Gold { get; set; }

    public Person(string name, double share = 1.0)
    {
        this.Name = name;            
        this.Share = share;
    }

    public void Stats()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("--{0} has {1} gold coins.", Name, Gold);
    }
}

public class Group : IFighter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Share { get; }
    public List<IFighter> Members { get; set; }

    public Group(string name, List<IFighter> members)
    {
        Name = name;
        Members = members;
        this.Share = 1;
    }    

    public int Gold
    {
      get
      {
        int totalGold=0;
        foreach (var member in Members)
        {
            totalGold += member.Gold;
        }
        return totalGold;
      }
      set
      {
        double sumShares = 0;
        foreach (var member in Members)
        {
          sumShares += member.Share;
        }
        var eachSplit = value / sumShares;
        var leftOver = value;
        foreach (var member in Members)
        {
            int memberShare = round(eachSplit * member.Share);
            member.Gold = memberShare;
            leftOver -= memberShare;
        }
        // Allocating the leftover amount left as an exercise for the reader ;-)
      }
    }

    public void Stats()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} has {1} gold coins.", this.Name, Gold);
        foreach (var member in Members)
        {
            member.Stats();
        }
    }
}
```